# Opencart, автоматический вывод товаров на категории

Tags: php, opencart

Вопрос,

Можно как то сделать автоматический вывод товаров на нужно категории, если товар прикреплен только к подкатегории.

**Например:**
**Категория(Цветы);
Подкатегория(Маленькие);
Товар(Тюльпан 01);**

Прикрепляем **Товар(Тюльпан 01)** только к подкатегории **Подкатегория(Маленькие)**, но не прикрепляем к категории **Категория(Цветы)**.

Как выводить **Товар(Тюльпан 01)** автоматически и в нужной категории **Категория(Цветы)**?

Есть какое-то решение или плагин?

Спасибо.

Comment: Дык, а почему не прикрепить к родительской категории?=)

Comment: На сайте уже много товаров которые не прикрепленны были изначально, нужно решение прикрепить автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в файле `catalog/controller/product/category.php` найти следующую строку

```
filter_sub_category' => true,
```

и закомментировать её.

Или попробуйте в файле `category.tpl` делать вывод товаров такой конструкцией:

```
if isset($subcategories) {
    <!--Код вывода товаров-->
}
```

Comment: Закомментировал, но не работает :(

Comment: Нашел по всему сайту и модули в которых, также закоментировал, все равно не работает.

Comment: @webEugene, попробуйте ещё один способ, добавил в ответ

Comment: Делаю так, но все равно не работает `<?php if isset($categories) {  foreach ($products as $product) { ?>` тут вывод товаров  `<?php }  } ?>`